# npx create-react-app showing error when installing

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I get below error when `npx create-react-app`. please help me how to solve this problem.

**nodejs version is v16.14.2** and **npm version is 8.5.0**

> To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
> npm audit fix --force
> (base) kiranrana@Kirans-MacBook-Pro react-app % npm install -g create-react-app
> npm ERR! code EACCES
> npm ERR! syscall rename
> npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app
> npm ERR! dest /usr/local/lib/node_modules/.create-react-app-DgI96EzL
> npm ERR! errno -13
> npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.create-react-app-DgI96EzL'
> npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, rename '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app' -> '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.create-react-app-DgI96EzL'] {
> npm ERR!   errno: -13,
> npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
> npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
> npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app',
> npm ERR!   dest: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/.create-react-app-DgI96EzL'
> npm ERR! }
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
> npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
> npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
> npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     /Users/kiranrana/.npm/_logs/2022-07-12T12_00_07_463Z-debug-0.log

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a `permission denied` error which could be caused due to incorrect installation of npm/node. Also, I just noticed that you are using `kiranrana@Kirans-MacBook-Pro react-app % npm install -g create-react-app` which is not recommended. I'd suggest you to use below command.

```bash
sudo npx create-react-app .
```